# Query inside while loop - mysqli with prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

There are two codes below - first that works using mysqli without prepared statements, and second that doesn't work using prepared statements. In the second, the problem is in second query that is in while loop. Have can i use query inside while loop using mysqli with prepared statements?

Code #1 works:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY topic_id DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

<?php   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $topic_id = $row['topic_id'];

  ?>

 <div class="brpostova col-md-2">Postova: 
         <?php
         $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM postovi WHERE post_topic = $topic_id ";
         $rezultat = $mysqli->query($sql2);
         echo $rezultat->num_rows;
?>

</div>
        <div class="autor col-md-2">Posted by <a href="#"><?php echo $row['topic_autor']; ?></a></div>

 <?php 
}
     $result->free
?>
```

Code #2 doesn't work:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY topic_id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $sadrzaj, $naslov, $datum, $kategorija, $autor, $sticky, $closed);

<?php while ($stmt->fetch())    {
      $topic_id = $id;

      ?>

     <div class="brpostova col-md-2">Postova: 
             <?php
             $post = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM postovi WHERE post_topic = ? ");
                  $post->bind_param('i', $topic_id);
                  $post->execute();
                  $post->store_result();
                  $numrows = $post->num_rows;
                  $post->close();
                echo $numrows
    ?>

    </div>
            <div class="autor col-md-2">Posted by <a href="#"><?php echo $autor; ?></a></div>

     <?php 
    }
         $stmt->free_result();
         $stmt->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: what not working ?some erors ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is this second query that is inside while ($stmt->fetch()  loop... It gives me this error - http://prntscr.com/3766up